# How to get the value of the last index in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, arraylist

Please i am trying to get the value of the last index in a list

the list is 3855 long

i try using `len(Atr["ADX"]) - 1`

but it's giving me 3829, which is not correct

so please guys how do get the last index
`

Comment: `Atr["ADX"].iloc[-1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you can get last index with this code
- a = {5,6,4,1,2,3}
- a[-1]
- its an example for you
- you can type index -1 and python gave you the last index